# How to prevent jQuery function from being initialized more than once (Drupal behaviours involved)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal, jquery-animate

**My goal:**
To enable a user to load a template (which contains preset jquery, html and css) to allow them to click one of five dots to trigger an animation on an image.

**My issue:**
When I load more than one of these templates to my page, my animation value (margin-left in this case) applies double the number of times that there is an instance of this template on the page. If my template is loaded twice, the margin-left sets to a value, jumps to the correct value, then back before finally setting on the correct value. This means that if I was to add 10 instances to the page, it would take 20 times as long to get that last value.

Before testing I thought that my code would be ok, as due to the context and `.once()`function, I believed it would only fire once.

All html and CSS are functioning as expected, it's just the jQuery is an issue.

**My code:**

```
(function ($) {
 Drupal.behaviors.click_the_dots = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
   $('.wrapper_class', context).once('click_the_dots', function () {
    // Prevent other buttons from being clickable until the
    // previous animation is complete.
    var animationDone = false;

    function clickDots(dotNum) {
      $('.dot_class_num_' + dotNum).click(function () {
        // Setup context, to keep animations to the container in which the dots exist.
        var findElem = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.inner_wrapper');
        // Prevent other buttons from being clickable until the
        // previous animation is complete.
        if (animationDone === false) {
          animationDone = true;
          // Find the visible image.
          var animatingImage = findElem.find('.dot_class_num_active');
          // Find the image that will be animating in.
          var thisImageAnim = findElem.find('.dot_num_img_src_' + dotNum);
          if (animatingImage.is(thisImageAnim)) {
            // Can't click on the same dot again, until another dot is clicked.
            animationDone = false;
            return;
          } else {
            // Animate out the already visible image.
            // Remove the visible image class as it's going to be hidden.
            findElem.find('.dot_class_num_active').removeClass('dot_class_num_active');
            // Animate it to hide to the left.
            animatingImage.animate({
              marginLeft: '-10%',
              opacity: 0
            }, 280, 'easeInOutQuad');
            // Animate in the image associated with the dot click
            // Set the image css to be further right in order to animate to left at 0.
            thisImageAnim.css('margin-left', '10%').delay(200).animate({
              marginLeft: '0',
              opacity: 1
            }, 300, 'easeInOutQuad', function () {
              // Set the now visible image to the visible image.
              thisImageAnim.addClass('dot_class_num_active');
            }).promise().done(function () {
              // Now allow the other dots to be clicked.
              animationDone = false;
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }

    // For each of the five dots.
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      clickDots(i);
    }
});}};})(jQuery);
```

I would like to add as many instances of this jQuery as required, but only have the function be looped through once. I'm not sure how to check if this has already been done, or how to ensure that once it has been done at least once, it shouldn't happen again.

:)

Comment: "I would like to add as many instances of this jQuery as required". No, jQuery (or any other script) should only be referenced once in any complete page that is rendered to the browser, no matter what. Otherwise you run the risk of unpredictable behaviour like you're describing.

Comment: @ADyson I think my wording was incorrect there. What I meant was I want to make sure that this jQuery is only added once, but that the template carrying it can be added numerous times. So is there a way to see if that jQuery behaviour or function has been added, and if it has, do not load it again? Or run it again...

Comment: I don't know about Drupal specifically, but the actual code itself could check whether a behaviour with that name already exists before adding itself.

Comment: @ADyson that makes sense to check...would you have an idea of how to go about this? I'm not sure how to check something in that scope

Comment: Can you check whether `Drupal.behaviors.click_the_dots` already exists (check if it's already an object)? Again I don't know exactly how Drupal works with all this stuff, but as a basic JS principle you could check whether the object exists and that should tell you whether it's already been defined.

Comment: @ADyson I will try something like that, thank you!

Comment: why dont you add a class to that element after processing the element in jQuery, and then add a condition if this class exists on the element or not.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki Drupal behaviours actually adds a class 'behaviourname-processed', but it does so immediately when the behaviour is attached - I was hoping it would add the class when the code within the behaviour had completed, but since it adds it immediately I can't use that class to help!

Comment: I would suggest use custom css class at first line of your code and use this class as a condition to process the element or not.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki that's a great idea...why didn't I think of that :D thank you, I will try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what my issue was - I was attaching the behaviour to the wrapper class of my content, i.e. `$('.wrapper_class', context).once...` - this meant that it attached the behaviour to each instance of this class, of which there could be many.

What I did was attach the behaviour to a higher parent element, of which I knew there would be only one instance. It attaches just once and the code works perfectly.

Thanks to the commenters above who helped me realise my issue!